# Enabling JWT Auth in DNN makes Pages and Users disappear

Tags: dotnetnuke, jwt, dnn9

I'm trying to use JWT Auth in DNN. After enabling it in web.config (code below), my pages and users list does not populate. (images attached). The extension has been installed and I added the code mentioned in http://www.dnnsoftware.com/docs/administrators/jwt/setup-jwt-for-auth.html

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<add name="JWTAuth" type="Dnn.AuthServices.Jwt.Auth.JwtAuthMessageHandler, Dnn.AuthServices.Jwt" enabled="true" defaultInclude="false" forceSSL="false" />
```

[No pages appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB7pH.png)

[No Users appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmBXY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of guessing, but ...

Did you install the extension?

Those pages are a bit out of date, and I don't know if the extension even supports the current versions of DNN.

Find the current docs from dnncommunity.org and see if the instructions or updated instructions are also there.

Comment: I did. I got this from dnncommunity.org (https://dnndocs.com/content/tutorials/jwt/setup-jwt-for-auth/index.html) and its the same as the one I posted.

Comment: Like I said -- I was guessing.  Have to tried the forums at dnncommunity.org?